# Uislider value when get back to minus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have a UISlider and it works ok if i want to change value to + , but when i'm get back to - , the effect is not ok . My app is a flashlight , and i change the frequncy for flesh from slider . Any ideea which can help me please ?

The index of slider is ok . This is my code.

```
 if ([self.lightON.currentImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"off-1.png"]]) {



         if (slider.value==0) {
               AVCaptureDevice * captDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
                      [captDevice lockForConfiguration:nil];
                      [captDevice setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                      [captDevice unlockForConfiguration];
           }

            if (slider.value==1){
                   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self                    selector:@selector(toggleFlashlight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
           if (slider.value==2) {
                 myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self                    selector:@selector(toggleFlashlight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
           }
           if (slider.value==3) {
               myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self                    selector:@selector(toggleFlashlight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
           }
           if (slider.value==4) {
                myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self                    selector:@selector(toggleFlashlight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

           }
           if (slider.value==5) {
               myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self                    selector:@selector(toggleFlashlight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

           }
       }
```

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Do you ever invalidate the timer?

Comment: it doesnt work to flashlight with the timer for slider.value . i invalidate the timer only when i want to stop the light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on the problem, but you should be invalidating the timer each time the slider is changed, and before you create the new timer. As it stands, each time you change the slider you will create a new timer so you will have many more calls to the toggle method than you are expecting.

Comment: @Nicole SD I believe this answer will help you . Not stopping NSTimer will be reason of unpredictable errors.